# Concurrent users in Load runner

Tags: .net, loadrunner

I'm new to testing. I need to test an ASP.net web application to identify how many users can use it concurrently using load runner.

Can someone please guide me to some examples on how to test this with Load Runner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been asked and answered at this location,

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lr-loadrunner/MgLsFB83y-M

Shotgun posting across forums is not considered polite behavior